# C++ implementation of `ThreadPool` does not work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, c++11, concurrency

I implemented a `ThreadPool` to test my knowledge of C++ concurrency. However, when I run the following code, it does not proceed and my mac becomes extremely slow and eventually does not respond—I check the monitor later and find the reason is that the `kernel_task` launches several `clang` processes and each runs nearly 100% CPU. I've carefully gone through the code several times, but still unable to locate the problem.

Here's the test code for `ThreadPool`. When I run this code, there is nothing printed on the terminal. Worse still, even if I cancel the process(via `contrl+c`), `kernel_task` creates several `clang` later and my computer crashes.

```cpp
// test code for ThreadPool
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

#include "thread_pool.hpp"

int task() {
    static std::atomic<int> i = 1;
    std::cout << i.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) << "task\n";
    return i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main() {
    ThreadPool<int()> thread_pool(1);
    auto f1 = thread_pool.submit(task, false);
    std::cout << "hello" << '\n';
    auto f2 = thread_pool.submit(task, false);
    std::cout << f1.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << f2.get() << '\n';
}
```

Here's the definition of `ThreadPool`.

```cpp
// thread_pool.hpp
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

#include "queue.hpp"

template<typename Func>
class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(std::size_t=std::thread::hardware_concurrency()); // should I minus one here for the main thread?
    ~ThreadPool();

    template<typename... Args, 
        typename ReturnType=typename std::result_of<std::decay_t<Func>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>::type>
    std::future<ReturnType> submit(Func f, bool local=true);
private:
    void worker_thread();
    void run_task();
    using LocalThreadType = std::queue<std::packaged_task<Func>>;
    static thread_local LocalThreadType local_queue;   // local queue, not used for now
    using ThreadSafeQueue = LockBasedQueue<std::packaged_task<int()>, 
                                   std::list<std::packaged_task<int()>>>;
    std::shared_ptr<ThreadSafeQueue> shared_queue;
    std::atomic_bool done;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

template<typename Func>
ThreadPool<Func>::ThreadPool(std::size_t n): done(false) {
    threads.emplace_back(&ThreadPool::worker_thread, this);
}

template<typename Func>
ThreadPool<Func>::~ThreadPool() {
    done.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    for (auto& t: threads)
        t.join();
}

template<typename Func>
template<typename...Args, 
    typename ReturnType>
std::future<ReturnType> ThreadPool<Func>::submit(Func f, bool local) {
    auto result = local? post_task(f, local_queue):
        post_task(f, *shared_queue);
    return result;
}

template<typename Func>
void ThreadPool<Func>::run_task() {
    if (!local_queue.empty()) {
        auto task = std::move(local_queue.front());
        local_queue.pop();
        task();
    }
    else {
        std::packaged_task<Func> task;
        auto flag = shared_queue->try_pop(task);
        if (flag)
            task();
        else {
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Func>
void ThreadPool<Func>::worker_thread() {
    while (!done.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        run_task();
    }
}

template<typename Func>
thread_local typename ThreadPool<Func>::LocalThreadType ThreadPool<Func>::local_queue = {};
```

Here's the definition of `post_task` and `LockBasedQueue`, which have passed the test code in the next code block.

```cpp
// queue.hpp
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>

template<typename T, typename Container>
class LockBasedQueue;   // forward declaration

template<typename Func, typename... Args, 
    typename ReturnType=typename std::result_of<std::decay_t<Func>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>::type,
    typename Container=std::list<Func>,
    typename ThreadQueue=LockBasedQueue<std::packaged_task<ReturnType(Args...)>, Container>>
std::future<ReturnType> post_task(Func f, ThreadQueue& task_queue) {
    std::packaged_task<ReturnType(Args...)> task(f);
    std::future res = task.get_future();
    task_queue.push(std::move(task));   // packaged_task is not copyable
    return res;
}

// the general template is omitted and it's not needed in this context
template<typename T>
class LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>> {
public:
    // constructors
    LockBasedQueue(): head(std::make_unique<Node>()), tail(head.get()) {}
    LockBasedQueue(LockBasedQueue&&);

    // assignments
    LockBasedQueue& operator=(LockBasedQueue&&);

    // general purpose operations
    void swap(LockBasedQueue&);
    bool empty() const;
    std::size_t size() const;

    // queue operations
    void push(const T&);
    void push(T&&);
    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args);
    T pop();
    bool try_pop(T&);
    // delete front() and back(), these functions may waste notifications. To enable these function, one should replace notify_one() with notify_all() in push() and emplace()
    T& front() = delete;
    const T& front() const = delete;
    T& back() = delete;
    const T& back() const = delete;
private:
    struct Node {
        std::unique_ptr<T> data;    // data is a pointer as it may be empty
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    };

    Node* get_tail() {
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        return tail;
    }
    Node* get_head() {
        std::lock_guard l(head_mutex);
        return head.get();
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> get_head_lock() {
        std::unique_lock l(head_mutex);
        data_cond.wait(l, [this] { return head.get() != get_tail(); });
        return l;
    }
    T pop_data() {
        auto data = std::move(*head->data);
        head = std::move(head->next);   // we move head to the next so that the tail is always valid
        return std::move(data);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    std::mutex head_mutex;
    Node* tail;
    std::mutex tail_mutex;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
};

template<typename T>
LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::LockBasedQueue(
    LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>&& other) {
    {
        std::scoped_lock l(head_mutex, other.head_mutex);
        head(std::move(other.data_queue));
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        tail = head.get();
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(other.tail_mutex);
        other.tail = nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>& 
LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::operator=(
    LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>&& rhs) {
    {
        std::scoped_lock l(head_mutex, rhs.head_mutex);
        head(std::move(rhs.data_queue));
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        tail = head.get();
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(rhs.tail_mutex);
        rhs.tail = nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::swap(
    LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>& other) {
    {
        std::scoped_lock l(head_mutex, other.head_mutex);
        head(std::move(other.data_queue));
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        tail = head.get();
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard l(other.tail_mutex);
        other.tail = other.head.get();
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline bool LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::empty() const {
    return get_head() == get_tail();
}

template<typename T>
std::size_t LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::size() const {
    int n = 0;
    std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);  // do not use get_tail() here to avoid race condition
    for (auto p = get_head(); p != tail; p = p->next.get())
        ++n;
    return n;
}

template<typename T>
void LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::push(const T& data) {
    push(T(data));
}

template<typename T>
void LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::push(T&& data) {
    {
        auto p = std::make_unique<Node>();
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        tail->data = std::make_unique<T>(std::move(data));   // we add data to the current tail, this allows us to move head to the next when popping
        tail->next = std::move(p);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
    data_cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
template<typename...Args>
void LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::emplace(Args&&... args) {
    {
        auto p = std::make_unique<Node>();
        std::lock_guard l(tail_mutex);
        tail->data = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        tail->next = std::move(p);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
    data_cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
T LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::pop() {
    auto l(get_head_lock());
    return pop_data();
}

template<typename T>
bool LockBasedQueue<T, std::list<T>>::try_pop(T& data) {
    std::lock_guard l(head_mutex);
    if (head.get() == get_tail())
        return false;
    data = pop_data();
    return true;
}
```

Here's the code I used to test `LockBasedQueue` and `post_task`. The following test code works without any problem.

```cpp
// test code for LockBasedQueue and post_task
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

#include "queue.hpp"

LockBasedQueue<std::packaged_task<int()>, std::list<std::packaged_task<int()>>> task_queue; // thread safe queue, which handles locks inside
void task_execution_thread() {
    bool x = true;
    while (x) { // for debugging purpose, we only execute this loop once
        auto task = task_queue.pop();   // Returns the front task and removes it from queue. Waits if task_queue is empty
        task(); // execute task
        x = false;
    }
}

int task() {
    static std::atomic<int> i = 1;
    std::cout << i.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) << "task\n";
    return i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(task_execution_thread);
    std::thread t2(task_execution_thread);
    auto f1 = post_task(task, task_queue);
    auto f2 = post_task(task, task_queue);
    std::cout << "f1: " << f1.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "f2: " << f2.get() << '\n';
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I test the code using `g++ -std=c++2a` on the MacOS 11.2.3.

Comment: *I omit all #include for simplicity* So anyone who want to test your code has to manually re-add them. Doesn't sound like it make anything any simpler.

Comment: is your problem when compiling or running the code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles My problem happens when running the code. @super. I've added `#include` now, thank you for the suggestions

Comment: code doesn't [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/GxGcb9), please provide a [mre]

Comment: Only an observation: your ThreadPool destructor might throw exceptions. I recommend to  handle them there in an appropriate way.

Comment: `shared_queue` seems to be null?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah. You're right, thank you so much. But do you know why it would cause my mac crash?

Comment: I suspect it doesn't and the crash is unrelated but undefined behaviour does mean anything can happen including crashing the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shared_queue` is default initialised therefore calling methods on it is undefined behaviour. Initialising it in the constructor of `ThreadPool`:

```
ThreadPool<Func>::ThreadPool(std::size_t n) : done(false), shared_queue(std::make_shared<ThreadSafeQueue>()) {
```

makes your code work: https://godbolt.org/z/P9G1T5